# transaction control in parent child packages ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, transactions, parent-child

I have parent package in which i have foreach loop for counting flat files and within it i process each file one by one while calling(Exec package task) child package where i have sequence container. While in child package sequence container i have two flow tasks 
-one is for deleting data from import schema tables and import all data from flat file into it which is passed by parent package.
-second is moving new and updated rows from import schema to the relative staging schema tables.

Now i set "required" transaction property for parent control flow while all other components in it are "supported".
and set "supported" transaction property for child control flow and same for all components in it. So when i execute the parent package it stuck at second flow task in the child package.

I want to rollback all transactions if any failure or error occur in any pacakge.

Please any help will be great.

Comment: Are you asking if you have transactions configured correctly in order to enable rollback in the event of failure or are you saying you have a problem in which the process "is stuck" at the second flow task?

Comment: I tried this approach to rollback all transactions in the packages while i got stuck in it . but if you recommend me another approach i can consider it.

Comment: It sounds like you have the packages configured correctly and that you have the MSDTC service running. But I am not clear about what the stuck part is?  Do you want to be able to kill the process and still have it somehow rollback, even though an error did not technically occur?

Comment: Actually i want to rollback all transactions if any failure occur in any package so i tried to configure the transactions property of both packages so that i can rollback all transactions but when i set those property i got stuck in second flow task of child package. So if you have any other strategy or solution please let me know.

Comment: Yes error or failure didnt occur but it got stuck in second flow task of child package(in validation phase beginning).

Comment: One more thing when i tried to execute with by default both packages control flows transaction property (supported) it didnt stuck while it was not satisfying the rollback of all transactions in any failure.

Answer (score 0):

If SSIS transactions are not working for you, consider re-architecting the package design.  Is it possible to break up the steps and stage data multiple times before finally committing it to the end result table.

I honestly never use transactions.  For an ETL process I break it out into 4 separate areas of concern:

1. Extract - Gets data as-is from source and physically stages it in a table.  The staging table will look exactly like the source table.  This minimizes interruption with locking in the source system.
2. Cleanse - Cleanses the data in place without consideration to other tables.  Cleansing can be performed in a view or with a separate package which stages the data.
3. Conform - Puts data from multiple sources into one table.  This table will look like target table (i.e. fact, dimension)
4. Load - Loads into the end result table, is only concerned with loading to minimize interruption to access of the table to end users.

I build in restartability to the packages so that if they have made it through the first few steps, they do not need to start over.  They can pick up where they left off and finish the ETL process.

If I had multiple files to extract from, I would build a package for each.  If there were a series of files with the same schema that needed to be looped through.  I would build the process with restartability in mind.  That is:

1. Truncate the staging table
2. Extract into the staging table one file at a time or in parallel
3. Archive the files

If the process were to fail, in this case, we can start from the top.  Because we are dumping the data into a staging table (which can be a heap) this can be a super fast efficient process.

If your main concern is that you do not want a particular end-result table in an inconsistent state, by staging the data, you can easily wrap the final insert/update process into a SQL transaction.

This is pretty general advice, but the gist of it is, don't use transactions, break the process into steps and use SQL transactions where it is actually needed.  Hope this helps.

Comment: let me explain you whole scenario or requirements:
1. Start auditing of package and count files in source folder.
2. Then store file information one by one in any table.
3. Then for each loop for file i have to create child package so that i can achieve atomic process for each file.
4. Child package have the two main tasks first truncate the import schema table and then insert file data as it is in that table. Then in second task merge the imported table data with staging table data.

Comment: 5. Then exit the child package and give control back to parent package.
6. Archive the file processed.
7. Audit the ending of package.

So i implemented each step while it was working fine with default transactions properties but when it comes to transaction control i configured accordingly but it got stuck in second task as mentioned in above 4th point.

Comment: I don't see anything in the Reqs that would compel you to use transactions. As long as the files are archived at the end, there is nothing to stop you from restarting from the top if there is an error.

Comment: Now i am using SQL transactions to control transactions. But thanks a lot mark for the helping to resolve it.